# Query rpm package version without locking rpmdb?

Tags: rpm, yum

When runnning `yum list installed | grep <package_name>` as a means to check a package version, on some hosts, this command can take some time because there might be other `yum` commands taking a lock on rpmdb.

Is there anyway via `yum`, `rpm`, or some other tool to check the version of an installed RPM without taking a lock on `rpmdb`?

Answer (score 0):

The command you search for is

```
yum list --installed kernel
```

(here `kernel` is example of package name)

The idea is to provide the name of the package and then you get the info about this package only (w/o usage of `grep`)